# SUM() data in a column based on another column data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a sql table

```
Project ID       Employee ID          Total Days

1                   100                   1
1                  100                   1
1                  100                   2
1                   100                   6
1                   200                   8
1                   200                   2
```

Now i need this table to look like

```
Project ID       Employee ID          Total Days

1                   100                   10
1                   200                   10
```

As iam new to sql,i am little confuse to use SUM() based on above condition.

Comment: Project ID = 2 for Employee ID=200 ????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two approaches

```
Declare @t Table(ProjectId Int, EmployeeId Int,TotalDays Int)
Insert Into @t Values(1,100,1),(1,100,1),(1,100,2),(1,100,6),(1,200,8),(1,200,2)
```

**Approach1:**

```
Select ProjectId,EmployeeId,TotalDays = Sum(TotalDays)
From @t 
Group By ProjectId,EmployeeId
```

**Approach2:**

```
;With Cte As(
Select 
    ProjectId
    ,EmployeeId
    ,TotalDays = Sum(TotalDays) Over(Partition By EmployeeId)
    ,Rn = Row_Number() Over(Partition By EmployeeId Order By EmployeeId)
From @t )
Select ProjectId,EmployeeId,TotalDays
From Cte Where Rn = 1
```

**Result**

```
ProjectId   EmployeeId  TotalDays
1            100        10
1            200        10
```

Answer (score 5):

This query below produces two columns: `EmployeeID`, `totalDays`.

```
SELECT  EmployeeID, SUM(totalDays) totalDays
FROM    tableName
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

*follow-up question: why is in your desired result the `projectId` is `1 and 2`?*

Comment: Sorry, The Project ID is same for all Employee's  .I just followed serial No ,Project ID is 1 for all

Comment: No,Project ID is 1 for all Employee's.My Apolozise, I typed wrongly.

Comment: so if that's the case and you want to include *project id*, `SELECT  ProjectID, EmployeeID, SUM(totalDays) totalDays
FROM    tableName
GROUP BY ProjectID, EmployeeID` you can further modify into this.

Answer (score 1):

```
select min("Project ID")as 'Project ID',"Employee ID"
   , SUM("Total Days") as 'Total Days'
from table1
group by "Employee ID"
```