# To create a column Summing the values from another column in the same view

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
View: 

A  | B
10   1
15   2
12   3
5    2
2    1
2    1

Output View: 

A | B | C
10  1   14
15  2   20
12  3   12 
5   2   20
2   1   14
2   1   14
```

I need to sum the values from column A based on column B. So, all the values from column B having value 1 extract values from column A and then sum it to column C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SUM() data in a column based on another column data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060782/sum-data-in-a-column-based-on-another-column-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the point, but:

```
SELECT t.a
    ,t.b
    ,sumtab.c
FROM [yourtable] t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t.b
        ,sum(t.a) AS C
    FROM [yourtable] t
    GROUP BY t.b

    ) AS sumtab
    ON t.b = sumtab.b
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SUM() OVER` like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    A int,
    B int
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
    A,
    B
)
VALUES
( 10, 1),
( 15, 2),
( 12, 3),
( 5 , 2),
( 2 , 1),
( 2 , 1)

SELECT *,
       sum(sd.A) OVER(PARTITION BY sd.B) AS C
FROM @SampleData sd
```

Returns

```
A   B   C
-----------
10  1   14
2   1   14
2   1   14
15  2   20
5   2   20
12  3   12
```

Comment: I think it's the same